# UWP C# WINUI NavigationView How to access other pages/views

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-iot-core, navigationview, winui

I am writing an app using `navigation view` basing on [Using the NavigationView in your UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/appconsult/using-the-navigationview-in-your-uwp-applications) tutorial.
I hope someone can help to clarify 2 things

1. what is the best practice to place my general routines? in the `MainPage.xaml.cs` or the `xaml` in respective views?
2. How do i update my `xaml` element such as `textblock` in a different view?
   eg.
   I have a `readHardwareID` routine run at startup to read the hardware ID in `MainPage.xaml.cs` How do I display the information in `InfoPage.xaml`.

my UI
[image: Main]
[image]

Please advise,
Thanks.

Updated: 06-08-2020

I am trying to pass a simple AppVerison `text` from MainPage to InfoPage to test out `OnNavigateTo`. However when I run the code and clicked on the `info` tab, I ran into this error.
[image]

MainPage Code

```
public String AppVersionName = "Test version 1.0";

private void nvTopLevelNav_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
        { 
            contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));    
        } else    
        {
            TextBlock ItemContent = args.InvokedItem as TextBlock;
            if (ItemContent != null)
            {
                switch (ItemContent.Tag)
                {
                    case "Nav_Home":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Devices":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(DevicesPage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Log":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(LogPage));
                        break;

                    case "Nav_Info":
                        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(InfoPage));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

InfoPage Code

```
public sealed partial class InfoPage : Page
{
    private MainPage mainPage;

    string appVersion; 

    public InfoPage(MainPage page)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        mainPage = page;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var data = e.Parameter;
        appVersion = mainPage.AppVersionName; 

        readHardwareID();
    }

    public void readHardwareID()
    {
        var deviceIdtoken = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
        var deviceId = deviceIdtoken.Id;
        var deviceIdReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(deviceId);

        byte[] deviceIdbytes = new byte[deviceId.Length];
        deviceIdReader.ReadBytes(deviceIdbytes);

        DeviceID.Text = BitConverter.ToString(deviceIdbytes);

        var sysIdToken = SystemIdentification.GetSystemIdForPublisher();
        var sysId = sysIdToken.Id;
        var sysIdReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(sysId);

        byte[] sysIdbytes = new byte[sysId.Length];
        sysIdReader.ReadBytes(sysIdbytes);

        SystemID.Text = BitConverter.ToString(sysIdbytes);

        // get the system family information
        string deviceFamily = AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily;
        Device.Text = deviceFamily;

        // get the system version number
        var deviceFamilyVersion = AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamilyVersion.ToString();
        var version = ulong.Parse(deviceFamilyVersion);
        var majorVersion = (version & 0xFFFF000000000000L) >> 48;
        var minorVersion = (version & 0x0000FFFF00000000L) >> 32;
        var buildVersion = (version & 0x00000000FFFF0000L) >> 16;
        var revisionVersion = (version & 0x000000000000FFFFL);
        var systemVersion = $"{majorVersion}.{minorVersion}.{buildVersion}.{revisionVersion}";
        OSVersion.Text = systemVersion.ToString();
        AppVersion.Text = appVersion;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best practice to place my general routines? in the MainPage.xaml.cs or the xaml in respective views?

If you want to use `NavigationView` as the app's base architecture, we suggest you use [Windows Template Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WASTeamAccount.WindowsTemplateStudio) to make `NavigationView` UWP template app. You could add the specific the page with `Windows Template Studio`. For more please refer link [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio).

> How do i update my xaml element such as textblock in a different view? eg. I have a readHardwareID routine run at startup to read the hardware ID in MainPage.xaml.cs How do I display the information in InfoPage.xaml

If you have load the data in the `MainPage`, you could use `Frame.Navigate` method to page the parameter  when navigate to `InfoPage` and getting the data from OnNavigatedTo override method.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    var data = e.Parameter;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how the `OnNavigatedTo` works. 
Should it be implemented on my `MainPage.xaml.cs` or `InfoPage.xaml.cs`? I have read up from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto?view=winrt-19041 
but there aren't much sample for me to refer to. 
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question where I tried around the routine but i ran into some error. Can you please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Please use this [Navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Frame_Navigate_Windows_UI_Xaml_Interop_TypeName_System_Object_) method to pass parameter.

Comment: I am still having difficulty to understand as I refered to other samples from GitHub UWP samples like xamlUIgallery,  I couldn't find examples passing data between pages.

Answer (score 3):

It could be very easy to solve this. Normally the NavigationView´s content is a specific user control. This example is very close to the one from the question but a little bit easier & without using "string mappings". It just exchanges  its specific content. The example does not consider calling up the settings.

C#:

```cs
private void NavigationViewControl_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    switch (sender.MenuItems.IndexOf(args.InvokedItemContainer))
    {
        case 0:
            sender.Content = new TripPlanning();
            break;
        case 1:
            sender.Content = new History();
            break;
        case 2:
            sender.Content = new About();
            break;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavigationViewControl" Background="LightBlue" IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                    IsSettingsVisible="False"
                    ItemInvoked="NavigationViewControl_ItemInvoked">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Haltestellen" x:Name="A" Icon="Map"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Letzte Abfragen" x:Name="B" Icon="Bookmarks"/>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Über die App" x:Name="C" Icon="Important"/>
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{x:Bind NavigationViewControl.CompactModeThresholdWidth}"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="NavigationViewControl.PaneDisplayMode" Value="Top"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple explanation of `navigation` from the link below.

As I am a hardware person without much software developing background, the official documentation with limited examples and reference confused me.

I suggest this simple example will be able to help a lot of beginners as it made it very simple , straight forward and clear.

[Pass parameters between UWP pages (common types string, int, and custom types)](https://www.programmersought.com/article/15953869626/)